# Display bytearray in a neat readable hex format

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

If I have a byte array

```
aaa=b'\x02\xc0\x00\x48\x04'
```

and I want to display it in hex, it will display the bytes as

```
b'\x02\xc0\x00H\x04'
```

which is a mixture of hex and ASCII characters. It is not neat to read when the array is too large.

The command I use is

```
print(' '.join(hex(n) for n in aaa))
```

The output is

```
0x2 0xc0 0x0 0x48 0x4
```

This is still different from my ideal representation:

```
02 C0 00 48 04
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: One option: `" ".join(f"{a:02X}" for a in aaa)`

Comment: other option `aaa.hex(' ').upper()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @furas.
The solution is

```
aaa.hex(' ').upper()
```

The result will be

```
'02 C0 00 48 04'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the strings:

```
' '.join(f'{:02X}' for n in aaa)
```